# Recreated iphone distribution certificate - want to configure existing Provisioning Profiles to use new cert?

Tags: iphone, certificate, distribution, profile, provisioning

My iphone distribution certificate was due to expire. I clicked the button next to the error message on the distribution certificate tab to recreate it, and followed the instructions to create a new certificate. (Note I used a new CSR - might this be a problem?).

The certificate was created sucessfully, and I want to move my existing provisioning profiles to use this new certificate. I've done some reading around on line, and it sounds like I should just have to click the "modify" button next to the prov profile and save it again with no changes. However, the modify button hasn't appeared. I've done the obvious web pages refreshes etc. But I'm out of ideas and can't find any info on this anywhere.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 2):

After you have got the new Distribution Certificate (you can revoke the old one and follow the steps in Apple's page to recreate CSR - using your Certificate Assistance in XCode), now in 
Provisioning>> Distribution, you will see all your profiles as INVALID.

There should be a Modify button next to INVALID status, once clicked, you may go inside and find out that the Submit button is disabled. Please click anywhere, recommended in the textbox of the App Name and the Submit button will be enabled. Just Submit and the Profile will becomes Active.

Hope this helps.